# winforms instrumentation . 

Tags: c#, winforms, instrumentation

What is the best pattern for instrumentation.  I have an application and i want to be able to track metrics on everytime a users does a number of functions in the app (brings up a form, views a certain feature, etc) but i dont want to have code all over the application that is doing this instrumentation.  what are my options here?

At the end of the day, i want to be able to aggregate data across multiple users listing out metrics.

Comment: Eqatec Analytics is a turn-key commercial solution. http://www.eqatec.com/Analytics/Overview.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been investigating doing something very similar (for an anonymous stats-collection library... kind of like Google Analytics, but for desktop apps. If you're interested, check out the GUI mockup [here](http://benjismith.net/index.php/gui-mockup-version-1/).)

Anyhow... for .NET, I've been looking at a few aspect-oriented libraries that provide dynamic and static instrumentation. I'm not sure whether they'll fit the bill yet (I haven't written any code yet; I've just started researching the libs). But here are a few prospects:

- http://dotspect.tigris.org/
- http://setpoint.codehaus.org/
- http://www.springframework.net/docs/1.2.0-RC1/reference/html/aop.html
- http://www.castleproject.org/aspectsharp/
- http://www.postsharp.org/

Good luck!